# MediaCodec error code -2001 during decoding

Tags: android, h.264, android-mediacodec

Since the AndroidDevelopers Google group won't let me post there, I hope that maybe here someone can help me.

Following problem: I have a working implementation of MediaCodec, both as encoder and decoder. The app I'm working on establishes a call between the device and a mediaserver, who sends an h264 video stream.

However, during decoding of this video stream, the MediaCodec decoder throws this error multiple times (btw no exceptions are thrown, only log messages):

> E/MFC_DEC_APP(1943): SsbSipMfcDecExe] IOCTL_MFC_DEC_EXE failed(ret : -2001)

Does anyone know what this error means? I was hoping there is some kind of error code list or static values somewhere in Android but so far I couldn't find anything.

The app ran on a Samsung Galaxy Tab with Android 4.1.2

Since the error does not occur on a call between to android device (aka p2p), it has to do something with the h264 stream the media server sends.

The error *seems* to only occur on p-frames.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: My experience has been that video drivers tend to log everything at "error" level, and complain noisily about things that aren't fatal errors.  Which makes it really hard to see actual problems.  If your app is working correctly I would ignore it.  In any event, this appears to be Samsung-specific, not Android-generic, but if you google for "IOCTL_MFC_DEC_EXE" you can find some instances of actual failures in which that message appeared.

Comment: The problem is that whenever the error occurs, last frame does not get decoded, which results in many visual artifacts when watching the stream. I would really like to fix this, but I just can't find out what's wrong with the frames.

Comment: Is the end-of-stream flag being set on a non-empty frame?  Some codec implementations will ignore the data if EOS is set, so you want to make sure the last frame is passed to the decoder without the EOS flag, followed by a zero-byte frame with the EOS flag.  (See also the examples at http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ .)

Comment: there is no EOS flag because the error occurs on a live stream. Actually, my app doesn't even have the capability to set an EOS flag. (but it does properly set the codec_config and sync_frame flags if necessary)

Comment: Ah... I was interpreting "last frame" differently.  Have you been able to test this on other types of devices to see if the problem only happens with the Tab?

Comment: So far I was able to test it on a Samsung Galaxy Tab and a Samsung Galaxy S3, the error occurs on both devices. I will try to test it on a non-Samsung device, but so far many devices don't even get to the point of throwing this error because of problems with color formats.

Comment: Just as a quick update to my last comment: I just tested it on the S4 and the error doesn't seem to occur there. But I'm not sure because on this device I can't take the frame out of the bytebuffer because the buffer at the decoderindex is null, which is very weird.

Comment: A set of CTS tests for mediacodec were added in Android 4.3 (you can see them on the bigflake.com site linked earlier).  The behavior on earlier releases was inconsistent across devices.  On 4.3 it's more reliable, but you still have to deal with color format issues when working with ByteBuffer (esp. when decoding on certain SoCs).  If you use a Surface instead -- which is expected to give you null buffers when decoding -- the color format issues go away and efficiency improves, but you can't access the raw YUV data.

Comment: I encounter this error with Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 Android 6.0 (CyanogenMod 13). The error is logged by /system/bin/mediaserver and a playback of live video is stopped just after this. I have tried to watch videos on youtube / rutube via Google Chrome but this error always appears after a few seconds.